# "You require permission from Administrators" to delete a folder even when I am admin

Tags: windows-8, permissions

I have a folder on my storage HDD that's taking up over 60 GB of space.  I don't use the contents any longer, wanted to obviously free up the space.  Only thing is I can't delete it.

Every attempt I get the following message:

> You require permission from Administrators to make changes to this folder.

I've looked at the folder permissions and it does show that my account (an administrator account and the only account on the PC) has full control over the folder.

How should I go about fixing the issue?  I've already attempted to use cmd.exe in admin mode to delete it with the 'del' command.  Guessing I'm going to have to go and change some permissions deep in the system.

Comment: have you attempted to take ownership of all objects in that folder? failing that, try downloading psexec from technet, and open a shell using `psexec -s \\. cmd.exe` and then try to delete the folder contents from that shell.

Comment: @Eric are you sure it's not an UAC message?
You could disable it, though in Win8 it require some registry editing.

Comment: @EliadTech It's not UAC.  I know this because it prompts me for the admin 'allow' pop up prior to the error message.  This was an Oracle Database folder, so it was installed with registry hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the permissions are not on all the sub-directories.
Try taking ownership and replacing it all the way down, and then try to force your permissions as well.

If that doesn't help, you can always do what ever you want from an external Live-OS like [HBCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) or [WinPE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749311%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).